# How to get left and right most indexes from matching word inside of string

Tags: python

With:

```
phrase = "this is string example....wow!!!"
word = "example"
```

I want to know what the left-most and right-most indexes are for a matching `word` inside of the `phrase`. How to do it with a minimum coding?

The output should be two integer values. First is the ordered number of the first letter of  `word`: "e". The second integer value is the ordered number of the last letter of `word`:  same character "e" (in "example" the first and the last letters are the same). We need to find where in the phase "this is string example....wow!!!" the word "example" is.

Comment: What is the output for `phrase = "example example"`?

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more specific. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so if a word appears several times in `phrase`, you're only interested in the first occurrence from the left? Then it's as simple as `(phrase.index(word), phrase.index(word) + len(word))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it without using the `re` package. It will also return the beginning/end indices of all occurrences of `word`:

```
phrase = "this is string example....wow!!!"
word = "example"

word_len = len(word) # word length is 7
phrase_len = len(phrase) # phrase length is 32

#We loop through the phrase using a "window" size equal to the word length
#If we find a match, we return the first and last index of the "current" window
for i in range(phrase_len - word_len+1):
    current = phrase[i:i+word_len]
    if current == word:
        print i,i+word_len-1

#prints 15, 21
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you only want to find the first occurrence of `word` in `phrase`. If that's the case, just use `str.index` to get the position of the first character. Then, add `len(word) - 1` to it to get the position of the last character.

```
start = phrase.index(word) # 15
end = start + len(word) - 1 # 21
```

If you need to find indexes of *all* occurrences of `word`, it's much easier to use the `re` module:

```
import re

for m in re.finditer(word, "example example"):
    print(m.start(), m.end() - 1)
```

Prints

```
0 6
8 14
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import re

phrase = "this example is  example string example....wow example!!!"
word = "example"

start, end = min([(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(word, phrase)])
print start, end - 1  # 5 11
print phrase[start:end]  # example
```